# Laravel Echo Cannot set property 'X-Socket-ID' of undefined

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, pusher

I recently upgraded to 5.3 from 5.2.

Last week I installed Laravel Echo, and am using it with Pusher, Vue and Vue-resource.

Everytime I post to my database I get this error

```
Cannot set property 'X-Socket-ID' of undefined
```

The doc says if you use Vue and Vue-resource X-Socket-ID is attached to the header automatically, but obviously no in this case

Does anyone got any ideas how to solve this?

Error comes from this code

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
            if (_this.socketId()) {
                request.headers['X-Socket-ID'] = _this.socketId();
            }
            next();
        });
```

main.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');
window.moment = require('moment');
require("moment/locale/ja.js");
window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Echo = new Echo({
 broadcaster: 'pusher',
 key: 'my key'
});
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Did you already `Vue.use(VueResource)`?

Comment: yes sir updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

solved after installing Vue-resource@^0.9.3